# Xen xl console terminates upon reboot command

Tags: xen, console, sles12

I am trying to troubleshoot the boot issue of Xen virtual guest and I need to access the grub menu.
I have attached a console to guest with `xl console` and in other terminal I have executed a command `xl reboot` which immediately closed my console.
Last thing I see on screen is a guest dmesg message `[ 2183.283059] reboot: Restarting system`

How can I keep the console connected across reboots?

Host System: SLES 12

Xen: xen-tools-4.5.1_12-2.3.x86_64 (provides xl command), xen-4.5.1_12-2.3.x86_64, xen-libs-4.5.1_12-2.3.x86_64)

Guest System SLES 12 SP1

Thanks